# ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage -> ADBannerView

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, iphone-privateapi

Apple has sent us this email:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app. Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app contains or inherits from non-public classes in Project: ADBannerView . If method names in
> your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering
> your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in
> future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above
> APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your
> app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the
> Technical Support Information at
> http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

I did some research and we don't have any class called ADBannerView, and the only reference to an object called `ADBannerView` is inside our `iAd` sdk implementation:

```
import iAd
private var adBannerView: ADBannerView!
```

`iAd` is from Apple... how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `ADBannerView` has been deprecated since iOS 10, so this is probably the reason.

Comment: Yeah. There is no reason to have any iAd code any more. It is defunct. Remove it.

Comment: @Paulw11 and what should I do to use iAd now?

Comment: iAd hasn't been serving ads [since 2016](https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/). You can still use it for search ad attribution, but that doesn't need an `ADBannerView`; remove that view

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, did you have a link to a migration guide for using the current "iAd" or alternative given by apple?

Comment: There is no alternative from Apple. They ended their in-app advertising business in 2016. If you want ads in your app then you will need to use some other advertising provider.